# How to use JSTL 1.2 on Tomcat 8?

Tags: jstl

I want to use JSTL 1.2 in my Tomcat 8 web app. I continue to get `JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application`. None of the other answers on the internet solve this problem for me.

I have verified that the jstl-1.2.jar is in my web app's `WEB-INF/lib` folder and my JSP has the newer, `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>` declared at the top.

If I open the jstl-1.2.jar file with 7zip, I can clearly see the `c.tld` file inside the `META-INF` folder and within that file I can even see this line: `<uri>http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core</uri>`.

I am not using maven, just copying jars into the WEB-INF/lib folder as needed. 
My web-app's `web.xml` file specifies it is web-app version 3.1

What else can I do to troubleshoot this? Also, is there any modern documentation on using JSTL? Oracle's docs end up [here](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jstl-api), which has almost no details on using JSTL, or even how to get it.

Webapp structure:

[image]

Comment: Can you give a screenshot of your project structure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, Tomcat's `catalina.properties` file had the `jarsToSkip` setting at `\*.jar`, so no jars would be scanned, resulting in quicker startup. To override this, I added `taglibs*.jar` (my jars were called `taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar` and `taglibs-standard-spec-1.2.5`, so it picked both up) to the `jarsToScan` setting below it, which fixed the problem.

I'm guessing that if jars aren't scanned, taglibs can't be found.

Tomcat's page has a nice write up of using taglibs [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/taglibs.html) with a helpful [readme](https://www.apache.org/dist/tomcat/taglibs/taglibs-standard-1.2.5/README_bin.txt).